# Why doesn't my linked list output pass this test?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking a coding challenge for linked lists in javascript. I haven't written a solution because I'm still trying to understand the basics.

Here's one of about 20 tests:

Input:
l: [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
k: 3

Expected Output:
[1, 2, 4, 5]

As a sort of hack to make sure I'm doing this right, I tried running the tests with this

```
function removeKFromList(l, k) {
 return { value: 1, next: { value: 2, next: { value: 4, next: { value: 5, next: null}}}};
}
```

Returning a linked list... but it doesn't pass. Then I simply returned the array

```
function removeKFromList(l, k) {
  return [1,2,4,5]
}
```

and it passed the first test.

Here's the question:
"Given a singly linked list of integers l and an integer k, remove all elements from list l that have a value equal to k."

My question is: Does l = [3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] count as a "linked list of integers"?

Comment: "Expected Output: [1, 2, 4, 5]" - I'm not sure why you thought that returning anything other than this would work. It's the _expected_ output.

Comment: But yes, I can see how that wording may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't, it's an array. However, it seems they're just giving the seed data, to leave the implementation (if you want) of the specifics of the linked list (along with seeding it) up to you completely. With that, means they need a uniform return which would be a 'seed' back to them (an array in order)

Comment: So I have to both convert the array to the linked list and then convert the linked list back to an array?

Comment: To be correct to the compsci terms, probably. However, javascript isn't really a language using linked lists in the traditional sense ever makes sense.